# jQuery post receive data with express

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, firebase-authentication

I am making a jQuery post request to the backend of my application. I am first using Firebase's auth to retrive the idToken of a user and send it to my backend to verify:

```
      var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
      user.getIdToken(true).then(function(idToken) {
        $.post('/setIdentity_learner', {Token: idToken}, () => {})
      });
```

And receiving it at my backend, check the token:

```
router.post('/setIdentity_learner', (req, res) => {
  console.log("passed");
  console.log(req.body.Token);

  admin.auth().verifyIdToken(req.body.Token).then((user) => {
    console.log(user);
  })
})
```

But this simple code return an error of: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'Token' of undefined`
I think I am not reading it correctly by using `req.body.Token`. How should I receive the token properly in my Express backend then?

I have already deployed these codes

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

I did quite a bit of research, and tried what is suggested but without any success.

Any thoughts? Thanks

Comment: Can you show the full app.js file?

Comment: I have a router file with `const Router = require('express').Router;
const router = new Router();` and am exporting it to a server.js file: `const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const server = require("http").Server(app);
const path = require("path");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const router_firebase = require("../firebase/router");
app.use(router_firebase);
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());`

Comment: After using router

Answer (score 1, accepted):

body-parser is an middleware so you need to use it before route. Put `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })); app.use(bodyParser.json());` before `app.use(router_firebase);` may help.